# Example of VCG mechanism

Tags: game-theory, economics, auction-theory

I have some problems in understanding the VCG (Vickrey-Clarke-Groves) mechanism in game theory. Actually the bid for player $j$ is defined as:

$p_j$ = (optimal welfare for the other players if player $j$ is not participating) - (welfare of the other players by the choosen outcome). 
Ofc. this can be formulated mathematically, but would need a lot of notations.

Now I have an example, where I would like to know the VGC outcome:

Consider a purchase of 800 kWh electrical energy. There are 6 providers, where player 1 and 2 offers each 800kWh at 50€, player 3-6 offers each 200kWh to 0€.

Now players 3-6 win the auction, and each one charges now:

$$p_j=(50€ + 0€ + 0€ + 0€)-(0€ + 0€ + 0€)=50€$$

So the buyer pays a total of 200€ for the 800kWh.

Is this the correct VGC outcome here?

Comment: http://www.matheplanet.com/matheplanet/nuke/html/viewtopic.php?topic=229352

Comment: Are the prices quoted per kWH or wholesome?

Comment: The prices are quetoed wholesome

Comment: What are the valuations of players? VCG presumes that $u_i = v_i + p$ and uses $v_j$ $(j \ne i$) to compute the price $p_i$.

Comment: @mlc each player has an incentive to bid honestly at their valuation

Comment: @Henry That does not answer my question: if $u_i (v_i, r_i) = -a(v_i-r_i)^2 + p$, $i$ has an incentive to report $r_i = v_i$ but it is $a$ that decides how strong is this incentive with respect to the payment received.